# Help me figure out what this cute little plant is Please :)

Tags: identification

I just bought this as a gift for my friend and no one can figure out what it is, I've googled all I can but I'm not familiar with plants so I have no idea what family its even in. Please help :) [image]

Answer (score 2):

It is called a ZZ plant, or more scientific *Zamioculcas zamiifolia*. It is a popular house plant, and quite easy to maintain. Not too much water, and good drainage. You can find a lot of info on internet about how to care for it.

Comment: Thank you! I told her and she looked it up :)